# How to refresh updated table rows in div using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need your help in refreshing the div="table" which it has a table that is retrieving its rows from the database.

```
<div id="table">
    <h1 id="Requests">
        <table></table>
    </h1>
</div> 
<button id="refresh-btn">Refresh Table</button>
```

I tried to use the below jquery, however it is refreshing the div without picking up the updates from the database.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   function RefreshTable() {
       $( "#table" ).load( "requests.html #table" );
   }

   $("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's loading an html file, which is static, so it's not going to query a database.  To get data from a database using ajax, you're going to need some type of service (node, php, .net, whatever) that has the functionality to query the db and format the output in html table rows.

Comment: I am using java, but how to update the table part only not the whole jsp

Comment: It's stupid but you could delete all the elements in table and put new values on your click function. The code may be table.innerHTML = '';

Comment: @99maas You stated the problem as, "...it is refreshing the div without picking up the updates from the database."  Maybe next time expand on what you mean when you use the term "it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete table

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

   function RefreshTable() {
   table.innerHTML = '';
   $( "#table" ).load( "requests.html #table" );
   }

   $("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);
});
```